# Convert 4D numpy array to image dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

new_stock is a 4d numpy array with shape (724, 1,30, 13). I want to convert it into image dataset for CNN model input.

I tried this:

```
    import imageio

    images = np.zeros((724,1,30, 13)) 
    for i in range(len(images)):
        imageio.imwrite('date_set_' + str(i) + '.jpg', images[i,:,:,:])
```

But got error

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-341-365e9f864a67> in <module>()
          3 images = np.zeros((724, 30, 1, 13))
          4 for i in range(len(images)):
    ----> 5     imageio.imwrite('date_set_' + str(i) + '.jpg', images[i,:,:,:])

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in imwrite(uri, im, format, **kwargs)
        251             pass
        252         else:
    --> 253             raise ValueError("Image must be 2D (grayscale, RGB, or RGBA).")
        254     else:
        255         raise ValueError("Image must be a numpy array.")

    ValueError: Image must be 2D (grayscale, RGB, or RGBA).
```

Comment: Why the duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481017/python-list-of-list-comparison

Comment: I have been trying using list as well data frame. But unable to find the result.

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you look into this!

Comment: What are the dimensions of each image? images should have either 1, 3, or 4 channels and MxN pixels. It looks like you're trying to create images that have either 13 or 30 channels and are 1 pixel long in one of the spatial dimensions. Perhaps you need to switch between the third and fourth dimensions.

Comment: Dimension of the image if 30x13(30 days of data with 13 features) which is counted as 1 feature. I want to save all small images into a data frame so that I can further use them.

Comment: try with `images = np.zeros((724,30 ,13, 1)) `

Comment: @Gulzar it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

making a slight change as shown in the image (changing the indexing of the image being saved to file) made it work for me. it created all 724 images.
[image]